# angularjs: checking the value in the view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view

I have `{{sales.description}}` in my view, that's used in the list (if that's a matter at all). It displays the text perfect, no question. However, I want it to display the same text, if that text is not equal to "test". Otherwise display "not available" (instead of "test").

What's the fastest way to check do it in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using ternary operator

`<span>{{sales.description=='test' ? 'not available':sales.description}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I'm not sure if that's the best way (I wrapped the text into , and I don't like it, but it works):

```
<span ng-if="sales.description=='test'">not available</span><span ng-if="sales.description!='test'">{{sales.description}}</span>
```

P.S. Once there are more than one specific cases, this solution is getting even worse.

Comment: Still waiting for a better solution. Please if anyone knows. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a better way to checking the value. You can try like as following sample:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        {{ sales.description == 'test' && 'test' || 'Not Available' }}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sales = {
        description: 'testfdsf'
    };
});
```

Hope this will help you!!